# How do I transfer my previous Grand Theft Auto Online character?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

We have just purchased an xbox 1 for my son for Christmas.  On his xbox360, he has a level 90 character for GTA 5.  How does he transfer his progress to his Xbox 1?

Comment: https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC#TransferToXBoxOne   Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

On the online tab in the pause menu it has a character transfer tab sign in to Rockstar Social Club (may do it automatically if he used the same xbox live account) wait a few minutes for it to transfer data (took a few days to get all of my money on ps4)